# Nopcommerce Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core-3.1

After moving sql server database to virtual machine, following error occurred,
I have already set the max pool size to max.

InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Comment: Assuming connections are being properly disposed in the code, check SQL activity to see if there are many connections actively running queries or being blocked.